# c# How to click a radio button on a webpage

Tags: c#, browser, controls

i have learned visual C# browser control.

But i got stuck at this thing. I want to click a radio button.  This is the html of the radio

```
<//input type="radio" class="radio" name="c" value="4" checked=""//>
```

Is there a way to click it?

Also if there are multiple radio buttons, how do i click the one with the value 4?

Comment: If someone gives you the correct answer you should click the tick so they get recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out all methods from [**HtmlDocument**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69b0ah2f.aspx) class. In special [**GetElementsByTagName**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx) and [**InvokeMember("Click")**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be9zzz62.aspx) to click on button.

**EDIT:**
I edit to make the answer complete: You need to something like this:

```
HtmlElementCollection es = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("radio");  
foreach (HtmlElement e in es)  {  
   if (e.GetAttribute("value") == "4") {  
        e.InvokeMember("Click");  
   }  
 }
```

Comment: Thaaaaaanks :)Works , you the best !

Comment: You are welcome. :) Don't forget to mark the question as accepted if it's exactly what you are looking for.